# Swift IOS 8 design elements are not showing on device

Tags: swift, ios8

I am developing an application in Swift for IOS8 running devices. I have designed my first screen. When I run the application on simulator all the design is shown perfectly. But when I run the application on a real device the screen is shown just blank. No elements and no background color which I have applied to the controller. I am using XCode6-Beta 3 and the device is IOS8 Beta 4.

What is the problem with that. Am I missing something in swift?[image: Device Image]

[image: Simulator Image]

Comment: Whenever you encounter unexpected behavior, especially with beta software, it is always a good idea to update to the latest version to see if there was a bug that was fixed ;). I recommend you upgrade to Xcode 6 beta 4

Comment: OK I am going to try that.

Comment: This really worked. Post your comment as an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you encounter unexpected behavior, especially with beta software, it is always a good idea to update to the latest version to see if there was a bug that was fixed ;). I recommend you upgrade to Xcode 6 beta 4